# How to pass an action to a child component in Elm

Tags: elm

I've only been trying out Elm for a few days and have come across what seems like a common scenario that I can't figure out.

I have a parent component that holds a list of items. To render the list, I have a child component such that the parent calls the view function of the child passing in the address and model. Since the Action types are different, I think the compiler is complaining about that, but I'm really not sure.

Parent Component:

```
type alias Model = List ToDoItem.Model

type Action
  = Remove Int

update : Action -> Model -> Model
update action model =
  case action of
    Remove id ->
      List.filter (\todo -> todo.id /= id) model

view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
view address model =
  let
    buildToDos =
      List.map (ToDoItem.view address) model
  in
    div [] [ buildToDos ]
```

Child Component:

```
type alias Model =
  { id : Int
  , name : String
  , description : String
  , complete: Bool
  }

type alias ID = Int

type Action
  = Toggle Bool

update : Action -> Model -> Model
update action model =
  case action of
    Toggle toggle ->
      if toggle == True then
          { model | complete = False }
      else
        { model | complete = True }

view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
view address model =
  let
    toggleText : Bool -> String
    toggleText complete =
      case complete of
        True -> "Incomplete"
        False -> "Complete"

  in

  div
    [ class "wrapper" ]
    [ span [] [ text ("[" ++ toString model.id ++ "]") ]
    , span [ class "name" ] [ text model.name ]
    , div [ class "description" ] [ text model.description ]
    , a [ onClick address (Toggle model.complete)] [ text (toggleText model.complete)]
    ]
```

Compiler Error:

```
 -- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------------------- 

The type annotation for `view` does not match its definition.

20│ view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The type annotation is saying:

    Address Action -> List ToDoItem.Model -> Html

But I am inferring that the definition has this type:

    Address ToDoItem.Action -> List ToDoItem.Model -> Html

-- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------------------- 

The 2nd argument to function `div` is causing a mismatch.

26│     div [] [ buildToDos ]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Function `div` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    List VirtualDom.Node

But it is:

    List (List Html)
```

How do I declare either the child component's view function correctly or pass in the parameters to the child's view function correctly from the parent?

In reality, I don't actually want to pass any action to the child component - I just want to render it. The action in the child component is for the onClick there.

Then again, maybe I'm way off because this is day 2 of my Elm life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Elm Architecture Tutorial](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial) covers the child view issue. Take another look at how the example 4 is implemented.

In short, you need to have an Action in the parent that wraps the child action:

```
type Action = Remove Int | ToDo Int ToDoItem.Action
```

And you need to forward this action to the appropriate Item in `update`.

In `view` you need to create a forwarding address for each of your ToDoItem views.

```
view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
view address model =
  let
    fwd idx = Signal.forwardTo address (ToDo idx)
    toDoList =
      List.indexedMap (\(idx, m) -> ToDoItem.view (fwd idx) m) model
  in
    div [] toDoList
```

Please note that your old `buildToDos` is already a list and saying `[buildToDos]` is actually saying `List (List Html)` which is why you got the second error.

Comment: Thanks. I have read over this example a number of times but it didn't seem to be what I needed. I don't actually need to forward the signal to the child component because it doesn't need to know anything about the parent actions. Can't I just call the child view fn with some sort of noOp or something?

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue based on this answer. I just created a NoOp action with a child component action associated - similar to what you had I just removed the index because I don't need it. Then I just sent that via Signal.forwardTo. The thing I'm still unclear about is how the signals flow. Does this need to happen with every parent child component relationship? Do actions always need to be forwarded?

Comment: If the ToDoItem has state of its own and actions to alter this state, than yes, this kind of delegation in update and forwarding in view is required. 

This is mainly generated by having a single state. 

[This image ](http://staltz.com/img/mvu-unidir-ui-arch.jpg) has a visual representation of what happens in Elm. 

With Elm architecture, people seldom use Signals. There is one big `Signal.foldp` inside StartApp and few `inputs` signals and that's it.

Comment: That's a great graphic, thanks. When you say people seldom use Signals in the Elm Architecture, do you mean Actions are used instead, or just that the composition is flat and nothing is usually passed down?

Comment: Yes, people use Actions. Signals are values over time and can be quite tricky to use. The Elm Architecture simplified things tremendously by dealing with time mainly in that big foldp that controls state. The rest of the app are regular functions with regular values, easy to understand, easy to compose.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler had already told you the answer. First of all, the

`Address Action -> List ToDoItem.Model -> Html`

The Action here has to be specified to the children Action. Just fix it like the compiler tell you:

`view : Signal.Address TodoItem.Action -> Model -> Html`

Second one, because you `buildToDos` is already a list, you just  need to:

`div [] buildToDos`

Spend some time understanding type annotation and follow compiler carefully then you are should be able to solve this kind of problem yourself.

Comment: I did try this before. The problem in changing that type signature is that I am using start-app and start-app expects the Signal.Address to be of type List ToDoItem.Model.